# why does my code run in idle but not in vim?

Tags: python-2.7, vim

i tried to run code in idle using F5 and it ran nicely

but i go to vim write the same code and do `:!python` and it gives this error

i know what indentetion is but it should not be giving it . how do i fix?

```
while True:
for i in range (90):
    print (str (i) + "is a number smaller than 90")
break
```

now i run it vim and it gives this

```
 File "<stdin>", line 2

           ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
for i in range (90):
    print (str (i) + "is a number smaller than 90")
break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing `:!python %` in Vim is essentially equivalent to doing `$ python filename` in your shell: the interpreter is fed a file and executes its content. What you get is not only perfectly normal and expected given the poor indentation of your file but also consistent:

```
# in Vim
:!python %
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    for i in range (90):
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

# in your shell
$ python filename
  File "<stdin>", line 2
    for i in range (90):
      ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

If anything, it is idle's reported behaviour that is surprising, here: your code is incorrect and can't be parsed by the `python` interpreter as-is so, if `<F5>` is really ignoring those errors and executing your code, then it means that it is doing something else than merely passing your file to the interpreter.

FWIW, this is what I get with your file in idle after pressing `<F5>`:

[image: idle]

which is consistent with `:!python %` and `$ python filename`.